# Java Maze SwingWorker - user input causes problem

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a maze where Monster Moves to Player every 1 second. It works perfectly fine, until I move the Player using KeyListener. After moving the Player, the MoveMonster method is still being called every 1 second but MoveMonster does not seem to Move the Monster after User-Input.
I am not that good with MultiThreading. Is my logic in using ScheduledExecutorService to call MonsterMover() that uses SwingWorker to call SwapCell() correct?
One last question, when I am debugging, I am not able to move the player i.e. User-Input addKeyListener() does not seem to be working, making it harder to debug.

```
public class Game extends JPanel {

    private Player player;
    private Monster monster;    

    public Game(int xSize, int ySize) {
        player = new Player(0,0);
        monster = new Monster(0,1);         
        setLayout(new GridLayout(ySize, xSize));
        addLevel();

        // Move Player Up, Down, Left or Right
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {  
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {                            
                    swapCells(getCurrentLevel().getMap()[x+dx][y+dy], getCurrentLevel().getMap()[x][y], player);                        
                }
            }
        });     

        // Move Monster every 1 second
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> moveMonster(), 0L, 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);        

    }   // End of Main Function                                         

    public void swapCells(Cell cell1, Cell cell2, Mover mover) {
        // Basically swap Cell1 with Cell2      
    }

    public void moveMonster() {             
        SwingWorker<Void, Cell> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Cell>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {                              
                swapCells(getCurrentLevel().getMap()[nextCell.getX()][nextCell.getY()], getCurrentLevel().getMap()[monster.getX()][monster.getY()], monster);  
                return null;
            }                       
        };          

        worker.execute();       
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Just remember, Swing is not thread safe, so if the input/UI is renitent on the data you changing in the worker you could have issues

Comment: Oh, and I'd avoid using `KeyListener` and use the key bindings API instead - it the related issues with `KeyListener

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hi Andrew. I do not know how to write a self contained example. I have changed my code to pseudoCodes, so its clearer and easier to read. I just want to know if my code's logic is correct, I will debug myself, as I will then learn more. Thank you!

Comment: *"I do not know how to write a self contained example."* Now is the time to learn. If there was anything you do not understand from the first (brief) document or the longer one which goes into more detail, ask. I wrote the 2nd one, and the initial draft of the first.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you very much Andrew. I will try to use this approach. It think it will help me a lot on my debugging skills in general. I am stuck at work right now. Will try this tomorrow on my day off.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hi Andrew. I recreated an example that works with Integer instead of custome Cell, however I could not recreate the problem. Which does not guarantee but leans more towards problem with my code rather than the way I am using thread. I want to debug my code but "in debuggin mode, I cannot interact with the GUI when ScheduledExecutorService is running".

Comment: *"I could not recreate the problem."* Cool! The thing to investigate now is, can you now (slowly, bit by bit) build that back up until it breaks, helping to narrow down where the problem lies? If you can narrow it down to "it broke when I added these three lines of code", it might make the answer obvious to you. Otherwise that code might still be short enough to post an an MRE / SSCCE that others can help with.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for your response. In the main class, I am calling moveMonster() inside a ScheduledExecutorService. Is that a wrong way of calling a method in Jpanel Constructor? Maybe this is what I did wrong.

Comment: @Pasang *"Just remember, Swing is not thread safe"* - You should only make updates the UI or state that the UI relies from inside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread